# Trouble with cmake while migrating noether to ROS 2

Tags: ros2, ros-iron

I'm currently trying to migrate [noether](https://github.com/ros-industrial/noether) package to ROS 2 and having lots of trouble getting it to build. I'm also having issues that the package is heavily integrated with ROS 1 packages, specifically the `ros/ros_comm/tree/noetic-devel/utilities/xmlrpcpp` package. My guess is that the `xmlrpcpp` is fundamental to ROS 1 and I'm not sure if ROS 2 was intending to use this ROS 1 functionality. Is there a ROS 2 replacement for `xmlrpcpp`? Or do i need to make a ROS 2 branch of `xmlrpcpp`?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! There has been a discussion going on this topic. Please look [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/noether/issues/165).